# Least populated time-zones

Tags: geography, time

What are there any loneliest places on earth in term of population per time-zone? What is the answer for full hour time-zones (UTC+1,UTC+2..) **and** in other including for example UTC+4:30?

SORRY
I may have actually meant, what is the loneliest time? When is the least amount of people awake (perhaps even including rare cycles; eclipses, solar minimums, etc)?

Thus, meaning that if you lived in the right place, at the right time, you would be one of the loneliest men on Earth.

Comment: [Eucla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B08:45) maybe? If you refer to IANA (TZ) zones, there are a number of the in Antarctica and remote islands with only a few researchers and seals (seals have no arms and can't use watches and researchers often use UTC so that would rather be 0 population).

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but when the Sun is shining above the middle of the Pacific Ocean, it's dark almost everywhere in the world (sort of kind of), so when it's noon in Hawaii, that might be the loneliest time, at least worldwide.

Answer (score 10):

There is one timezone that is **completely uninhabited**: the [UTC-12:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9212:00). It covers only two islands: Baker Island and Howland Island that are both uninhabited (owned by US). Because of the weird way timezones are divided in the pacific there are timezones that practically use the same time (e.g. UTC+12 and UTC-12), but are actually in two different days. However if you strictly interpret the question no-one is lonely here as there is no-one here, so this might not comply.

The second least population is at [UTC+08:45](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B08:45) that covers village of Eucla and other villages in Australia with a population of around 200. The area is surrounded by signs to remind you to turn your clocks, but it is unofficial so it might not comply either.

The third least population is at [UTC+10:30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Howe_Island) that covers an island called the Lord Howe Island that belongs to Australia and is inhabited by 382 people. If you don't accept timezones that aren't in integer changes from UTC then this UTC+10:30 might not satisfy your curiosity.

The first full integer timezone shift from UTC (that has any population) is [UTC-02:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9202:00) that consists of Atlantic islands of Brazil like Fernando de Noronha, Trindade, Martim Vaz etc. Also South Georgia and South Sandwich Islands of UK belong in this timezone. The total population then is somewhere around 2700 people. Unfortunately these are the places that use this timezone all year round and other areas like densely populated Brazilian cities use this timezone as daylight saving during their summer increasing the population drastically so even this timezone might not satisfy your criteria.

Finally [UTC-11:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9211:00) being full integer change from UTC, with only all year round usage (isn't a daylight saving timezone for anyplace) consists of American Samoa, Midway Atoll, Jarvis Island and Palmyra Atoll of US and Niue of New Zealand and has under 60000 inhabitants.

**Ps**. The estimated population numbers are from the wikipedia pages of the locations mentioned.

Comment: You knew all of that off of the top of your head!?!?!  If not, perhaps let us in on your source?

Comment: The wikipedia pages I linked display all timezones compactly, they also tell what countries/islands are in those timezones. The population numbers are also based on the wikipedia pages of the given islands. Of course wikipedia isn't always the most reliable source, but I found no reason why not to trust these pages... Please correct me if I made an error somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't intending to dispute the answer, and have no particular problem with Wikipedia, it's a great resource so long as folks are mindful of its shortcomings.  Just thought there should be some kind of place to go look into the information further, if one wanted to further research or was suspect of what you'd said.  Consider it the teacher in me immediately screaming REFERENCES when someone makes a claim around here :-p

Comment: Critique accepted. I should've stated where my numbers are from.

Answer (score 1):

Communisty has done a good job of giving the winners in various categories, but I think it's also worth mentioning the runner-up [UTC+12:45](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B12:45), which is only used by the [Chatham Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatham_Islands#Chathams_time), population 600. But UTC-12:00 beats this one, unless there happen to be enough ships in UTC-12:00 to furnish more than 600 people. And UTC+10:30 with 382 people seems indisputably lonelier.

[UTC+08:45](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B08:45), mentioned by Tbb in the comments, is another candidate, but as the Wikipedia article says it's not officially recognized.